# Initalizing the nested anonymous structures

Tags: go, struct

I am having a json as

```
{
"fields": ["time","id","status","customerId","additionalDetail"],
"pageInfo": {"start": 0, "rows": 1000}
}
```

I wanted to Marshal my structure to above json and create the structure as below -

```
type RBody struct {
Fields []string `json:"fields"`
PageInfo struct {
    Start int `json:"start"`
    Rows int `json:"start"`
    } `json:"pageInfo"`
}
```

I am having trouble in initializing the above structure. I am not sure how to initialize the anonymous struct in below fashion :

```
bd := RBody {
Fields : []string{"time","id","status","customerId","additionalDetail"},
PageInfo : ???
}
```

I worked around this by creating a separate structure for page info and attaching that with parent struct. However there's got to be some way to perform the initialisation of the **anonymous** nested struct, in the same way I did with **Fields** (string slice) above. Can anyone redirect me to some guide to do that ?

Comment: You should be able to do `RBody{ ... struct{Start, Rows int}{ Start: 42, Rows: 42}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but it is ugly:

```
bd := RBody { Fields :  []string{"time","id","status","customerId","additionalDetail"},
PageInfo : struct {Start int `json:"start"`
Rows int `json:"rows"`} {Start:1,Rows:2}}
```

I suggest you either name the anonymous struct, or initialize Fields in the declaration, and PageInfo using assignments later.

Comment: Cool. As I said, I got that working by naming the anonymous struct which is definitely "not ugly" but just wanted to know if there's a way around that.